# Single Image Transition from Right to Left using FFMPEG and stop at end

Tags: ffmpeg

I am having a single Image which I want to slide (Transition) from right to Left and stop at the end point and convert that into Video using FFMPEG. Although there are many posts regarding transitions but I couldn't find transition for single image to Video.

I had used the solution from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/727379/how-to-make-left-right-transition-of-overlay-image-ffmpeg):

`ffmpeg -i C:\Sagar\Projects\Demos\Canvas\Canvas\BoxImage\1\output.png -i C:\Sagar\Projects\Demos\Canvas\Canvas\BoxImage\1\output.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=x='if(lte(-w+(t)*100,w/2),-w+(t)*100,w/2)':y=0[out]" -map '[out]' -y C:\Sagar\Projects\Demos\Canvas\Canvas\BoxImage\1\outputout.mp4`

but gives an error "Invalid stream specifier [out]":

[image: Invalid stream specifier [out]]

I have also tried

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "color=black:d=15:s=1920x1080[background];movie='C:\Sagar\Projects\Demos\Canvas\Canvas\BoxImage\2\output.png' [overlay];[background][overlay]overlay='W-n:(H-h)/2'" C:\Sagar\Projects\Demos\Canvas\Canvas\BoxImage\2\outputoutput.mp4
```

But it still gives me error as below

[image: error 2]

Comment: Please read the second answer to the other question. You only tried the first answer.

Comment: Please recheck the edited question @slhck

Comment: I think you have to escape the backslashes: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/2166 and https://superuser.com/a/904366/48078

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want the background to be black, use

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i img.png -filter_complex 
       "split=2[bg][slider];[bg]drawbox=c=black:t=fill[bg];
        [bg][slider]overlay=x='max(W-(w/4)*t,0)':y=0" -t 10 out.mp4
```

This will create a 10-second video in which the the images slides from right to left in 4 seconds and then stops there.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But this video shows Image on load and then slide, I want - when video starts the image should slide from right towards left and stop when it reaches to center. I want exact opposite of your output. i.e. first there will be black background and then it will slide from right to left to show my image and stop.

Comment: Corrected......

Comment: Hi, Can I set the Output video in 1024x576 resolution?

Comment: Add `scale=1024:576,setsar=1` after the overlay.